# What does error_already_set in Boost.python do and how to handle exceptions similarly in Python C API

Tags: python, c++, exception, boost-python, python-c-api

I have been working on a project where I want to remove the boost dependencies and replace it with the Python C API.

I spent some time understanding the Python C API and I saw this
`catch (error_already_set const &)`

I read the boost docs but it explains where it is used. But I want to know why it is needed and how can I achieve the same functionality using the native Python C api.

Comment: [This blog](https://misspent.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/boost-python-and-handling-python-exceptions/) explains the meaning of `error_already_set` and how you can figure out what actually happened on the Python side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost throws `error_already_set` when a Python error has occurred.  So if you see code like this:

```
try {
    bp::exec(bp::str("garbage code is garbage"));
} catch (const bp::error_already_set&) {
    // your code here to examine Python traceback etc.
}
```

you'll replace it with:

```
your_ptr<PyObject> res = PyRun_String("garbage code is garbage");
if (!res) {
    // your code here to examine Python traceback etc.
}
```

In other words, wherever you see `catch(error_already_set)`, there you will likely want to do some error handling using whatever `PyObject*` or other value is involved to recognize when an error has occurred (and therefore you can examine the traceback, or convert it into a C++ exception).