# how to start embedded python xmlrpc server in the background while C++ application is running?

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I want to develop a test program to test a C++ application using embedded python.  This is an example I want to modify: https://github.com/skebanga/py_embed.

What I want to do is instead of hardcoding 5 in test.py. I want to pass different values for different test cases. Is it possible?

Before the modification: the output of the example above is

```
./my_program
created script
running
result=10
```

My idea is to add xmlrpcserver to test.py to accept inputs. After I changed test.py as below, rebuilt and ran,  the thread is hold by xmlrpc server. When exit, an error will be thrown as below.

Any suggestions?

```
./my_program

    Listening on port 8000 ...
    Hello
    127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2018 15:06:34] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

    ^Cterminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::python::error_already_set'
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

The modified test.py

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

class Script(object):
    def __init__(self, ifc):
        print 'created script'
        self.ifc = ifc

    def run(self):
        print 'running'
        self.ifc.execute(5)
        self.startRPC()

    def result(self, i):
        print 'result={}'.format(i)

    def startRPC(self):
       server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("", 8000), allow_none=True)
       print ("Listening on port 8000 ...")
       server.register_instance(self)
       server.serve_forever()
```

I changed test.py as updated above.
I also added try and catch to main()

```
 int main(){
    try{
    ....
    } catch (const bp::error_already_set&)
    {

        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The output is now:

```
./my_program
created script
running
result=10
Listening on port 8000 ...
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in run
    self.startRPC()
  File "test.py", line 31, in startRPC
    server.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 236, in serve_forever
    poll_interval)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 155, in _eintr_retry
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Actually I notice there is no more core dump. Is it because the exception is caught?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: First step would probably be adding to your c++ code some handling of the boost::python exception and extracting/printing the information it holds about the error that occurred. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094001/what-does-error-already-set-in-boost-python-do-and-how-to-handle-exceptions-simi

Comment: I added try{...} catch (const bp::error_already_set&){PyErr_print();} now the output ./my_program
created script
running
result=10
Listening on port 8000 ...
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in run
    self.startRPC()
  File "test.py", line 31, in startRPC
    server.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 236, in serve_forever
    poll_interval)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 155, in _eintr_retry
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Could you, please, [edit] your question and add those details? It's really hard trying to parse the backtrace from an unformatted comment. Cheers

Comment: At this point, you catch the exception on the C++ side, which lets you see the backtrace (so now you can debug the Python script easily) and terminate gracefully. Now that you know that it's a `KeyboardInterrupt`, you could add some more specific handling of that somewhere in your code