# Got exception boost::python::error_already_set on boost::python::import("cv2")

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I got exception `boost::python::error_already_set` thrown out on calling `boost::python::import("cv2")`

First, I wrote a python script `pymod.py`:

```py
import sys
...
```

and import the `pymod.py` with `boost::python` in cpp code:

```cpp
...
boost::python::import("pymod");
...
```

works well.

But when I add `cv2` in the `pymod.py`:

```py
import sys, cv2
```

the `boost::python::import("pymod")` threw an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::python::error_already_set'
```

Notice that the python script with `import cv2` can be called by python:

```sh
python pymod.py
```

with no error.

So I tried a cpp version of importing `cv2` with `boost::python` and the same exception is threw out. The code as following:

```cpp
#include <boost/dll/import.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main(int nArgCnt, char *ppArgs[]) {
    Py_Initialize();
    boost::python::object pySys = boost::python::import("cv2");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Update 1:

I also have checked the source `boost_1_65_1/libs/python/src/import.cpp` and found the implementation of `boost::python::import`:

```cpp
object BOOST_PYTHON_DECL import(str name)
{
  // should be 'char const *' but older python versions don't use 'const' yet.
  char *n = python::extract<char *>(name);
  python::handle<> module(PyImport_ImportModule(n));
  return python::object(module);
}
```

And I try to directly use `PyImport_ImportModule`, but it also failed:

```cpp
#include <boost/dll/import.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int nArgCnt, char *ppArgs[]) {
    Py_Initialize();
    // numpy, sys and other modules can be load! VERY STRANGE!!
    auto pMod = PyImport_ImportModule("cv2");
    std::cout << pMod << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

this code print following outputs:

```sh
['/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6', '/home/devymex/3rdparty/opencv-4.0.1/build/python_loader', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/devymex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mxnet-1.3.1-py3.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/graphviz-0.8.4-py3.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/typing-3.6.6-py3.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/typing_extensions-3.6.6-py3.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnx-1.5.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
0
```

But I'm very sure the command `python3 -c "import cv2"` works no problem. So it  seem irrelevant with boost.

---

Update 2:

`PyErr_Print();` gives following information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 79, in bootstrap
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 23, in bootstrap
    raise ImportError('ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.')
ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.
```

`__init__.py`:

```py
'''
OpenCV Python binary extension loader
'''
import os
import sys

try:
    import numpy
    import numpy.core.multiarray
except ImportError:
    print('OpenCV bindings requires "numpy" package.')
    print('Install it via command:')
    print('    pip install numpy')
    raise

# TODO
# is_x64 = sys.maxsize > 2**32

def bootstrap():
    import sys
    if hasattr(sys, 'OpenCV_LOADER'):
        print(sys.path)
        raise ImportError('ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.')
    sys.OpenCV_LOADER = True

    DEBUG = False
    if hasattr(sys, 'OpenCV_LOADER_DEBUG'):
        DEBUG = True

    import platform
    if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: os.name="{}"  platform.system()="{}"'.format(os.name, str(platform.system())))

    LOADER_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS = []
    BINARIES_PATHS = []

    g_vars = globals()
    l_vars = locals()

    if sys.version_info[:2] < (3, 0):
        from cv2.load_config_py2 import exec_file_wrapper
    else:
        from . load_config_py3 import exec_file_wrapper

    def load_first_config(fnames, required=True):
        for fname in fnames:
            fpath = os.path.join(LOADER_DIR, fname)
            if not os.path.exists(fpath):
                if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: config not found, skip: {}'.format(fpath))
                continue
            if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: loading config: {}'.format(fpath))
            exec_file_wrapper(fpath, g_vars, l_vars)
            return True
        if required:
            raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))

    load_first_config(['config.py'], True)
    load_first_config([
        'config-{}.{}.py'.format(sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1]),
        'config-{}.py'.format(sys.version_info[0])
    ], True)

    if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS={}'.format(str(l_vars['PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS'])))
    if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: BINARIES_PATHS={}'.format(str(l_vars['BINARIES_PATHS'])))

    for p in reversed(l_vars['PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS']):
        sys.path.insert(1, p)

    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.environ['PATH'] = ';'.join(l_vars['BINARIES_PATHS']) + ';' + os.environ.get('PATH', '')
        if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: PATH={}'.format(str(os.environ['PATH'])))
    else:
        # amending of LD_LIBRARY_PATH works for sub-processes only
        os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = ':'.join(l_vars['BINARIES_PATHS']) + ':' + os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '')

    if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: replacing cv2 module')
    del sys.modules['cv2']
    import cv2

    try:
        import sys
        del sys.OpenCV_LOADER
    except:
        pass

    if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: DONE')

bootstrap()
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094001/what-does-error-already-set-in-boost-python-do-and-how-to-handle-exceptions-simi

Comment: @Richard Thanks, I check the source of boost::python::import and did some other testing, please view my updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution:

```cpp
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
#include <boost/python/extract.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace py = boost::python;

int main(int nArgCnt, char *ppArgs[]) {
    Py_Initialize();
    py::object pySys = py::import("sys");
    auto pySysPaths = py::extract<py::list>(pySys.attr("path"))();

    //Important! Add an empty path to the head of searching paths
    pySysPaths.insert<std::string>(0, "");

    py::object pyCv2 = py::import("cv2");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Explanation

If you use command `python some_script.py`, the list of searching path of modules has been modified: a empty path string would be insert into the head of the list:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', blah, blah, blah, ...]
```

You can find line 67, 68 of `__init__.py` of OpenCV:

```py
    for p in reversed(l_vars['PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS']):
        sys.path.insert(1, p)
```

Then the path of OpenCV library (`cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`) is properly inserted into the list. And `import cv2` in line 79 of `__init__.py` just loading the `cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file directly, everything works well with another searching path up to now.

But things are different in cpp calling. Without the `python` program, nobody add the empty searching path into head of `sys.path`, so the `__init__.py` generated an undeserved list of searching path:

```
['/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6', '/home/devymex/3rdparty/caffe/python', blah, blah, blah, ...]
```

Notice the real location of `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` is in the second place, so line 79 in `__init__.py` entered into a recursive calling of `__init__.py` instead of loading `cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

That's the whole story.